# How does this abstract repetition works?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm reading some Javascript stuff since i dream about being a good JS developer. I kind of know how to use the basics to fullfill my PHP needs, but there are still some doubts.

I saw some some examples and got this:

```js
function repeat(n, action) {
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      action(i);
   }
}

let labels = [];

repeat(5, i => {
   labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});

console.log(labels);
```

So, i can use it to repeat some basic function if needed. Understood, but in another case, i could use the same function with some different approach.

Why does the variable **i** becomes a counter/iterator if I suppose to pass a function?

I've used it before all time, but still don't know how does it works, so i can't use it when trully needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` isn't becoming an iterator. In the code, you are using es6 shorthand notation for describing a function. `i` is the lone argument to the function.

```
i => {
   labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
```

is the same as

```
function(i){
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

Please see more in this [reference on shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Edit: To answer your comment "What is adding it", you must look at the `repeat(n, action)` function more closely. It also may be confusing to you that `i` is used in both cases so I will rewrite the function to help you understand. This function uses a for loop to iterate from 0 to `n`

```
for (let idx = 0; idx < n; idx++) {
   action(idx);
}
```

and invokes the action with the current for loop index `idx`. So for you example:

```
Iteration 0: action(0) -> labels.push(`Unit ${0 + 1}`);
Iteration 1: action(1) -> labels.push(`Unit ${1 + 1}`);
Iteration 2: action(2) -> labels.push(`Unit ${2 + 1}`);
Iteration 3: action(3) -> labels.push(`Unit ${3 + 1}`);
Iteration 4: action(4) -> labels.push(`Unit ${4 + 1}`);
```

Please do note that the `repeat`'s declaration of `i` is local to its function body, just as the `i` in `i => { labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`); }` is local to its function body. These two `i` values are not referencing the same value in memory and can be renamed as I did in my explanation

Comment: But why `i` still getting up, what is adding it?

Comment: @VictorAugusto the `repeat` function is calling `action(i)`. And here `action` is the function `i => { labels.push(\`Unit ${i + 1}\`); }`. For clarity, this is similar to `function(i) { labels.push(\`Unit ${i + 1}\`); }`. So `repeat` is calling *that* function and supplying `i` from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In `repeat` function you are passing forloop index to callback

```
function repeat(n, action) {
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      action(i); // here you are passing index to callback
   }
}
```

and you are getting index as params

```
repeat(5, i => { // Here you will get params that is passed by repeat function
   labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

This is the original function

```
repeat(5, i => {
   labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
```

which can be written as

```
repeat(5, function (i) {
    labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
```

Make the anonymous function a named one like this,

```
var action = function(i){
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

Then `repeat` call becomes, `repeat(5, action);` //action is function reference

Now we can change the function definition like this removing the `action` function reference

```
function repeat(n) {
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     action(i);
   }
}
var action = function(i){
  labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
}
```

This could be simplified as,

```
function repeat(n) {
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
   }
}
```

Result will be `["Unit 1", "Unit 2", "Unit 3", "Unit 4", "Unit 5"]` in console.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit confusing that you use `i` as a variable in the `for` loop as well as the parameter of your arrow function. Changing the function parameter to `x` and seeing that it still works, might lead to a better understanding of the variable scopes and makes it easier to explain:

```
repeat(5, x => {
   labels.push(`Unit ${x + 1}`);
});
```

You are passing the arrow function to the `repeat()` function. Inside the repeat function, the `for` loop increases `i` on every iteration, in this case from 0 to 4, and each time calls the arrow function that you passed as the `action` parameter. This function's `x` parameter will take on the value of `i`, because you pass it as the first argument upon calling the `action` reference (i.e. the arrow function).

Answer (score 0):

`repeat` function receives callback and every iteration passes to this callback current value of `i`